# Can't extend backbone.events in coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, extends

I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

When declaring the following class:

```
 class ViewHelpers extends Backbone.Events
```

I can use the same syntax to extend Backbone.Router, Views, Model etc. Here is the compiled javascript which I wrote in a quick log to make sure Backbone.Events was there

```
__t('views').ViewHelpers = (function(_super) {

 #how i know it is definied here
 console.log(_super.trigger)

 __extends(ViewHelpers, _super);

 function ViewHelpers() {
   return ViewHelpers.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
 }

 return ViewHelpers;

})(Backbone.Events);
```

So the line causing the error is

```
ViewHelpers.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
```

What is different about __extends() method that it would work for Backbone.View and not Backbone.Events?

Comment: I've commented on the difference between Backbone.Events and other Backbone objects in an answer below, but, i'd like to ask: what's the purpose of ViewHelpers? Because its name is not the typical name for classes (i.e. singular nouns) so it might be the case that a class is not what you need.

Comment: Great answer below thanks! I agree helpers are generally defined at a global scope. In this case I maintain a library of functions in a class ViewHelpers, instantiated as a property of my main controller class. There are some functions (for example, CSS transitionEnd handlers) which I may want to subscribe multiple listeners instead of passing a single callback. Since I'm already using Backbone I thought I'd subclass the Event "class" (object) for that purpose. Sorry to be late on this reply, not sure why I didn't get notified months ago.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's because `Backbone.Events` is not a "class", so it cannot be extended, it's a "module" that can be mixed-in into other objects (see docs [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Events)). In JavaScript terms that means that it's not a `Function`, that can be called as a constructor (i.e. `new Backbone.Events` will throw an error), it's just a plain JS object whose properties (methods) can be assigned to other objects to make them event dispatchers.

In CoffeeScript, you can mix-in the `Backbone.Events` into your objects when they are created:

```
class ViewHelpers
  constructor: ->
    _.extend @, Backbone.Events
```

Or you can just extend the class' prototype and avoid having those methods as (own) properties of all `ViewHelpers` instances:

```
class ViewHelpers
  _.extend @prototype, Backbone.Events
```

These two approaches should work and let you instantiate and use ViewHelpers as event dispatchers:

```
vh = new ViewHelpers
vh.on 'foo', -> alert 'bar'
vh.trigger 'foo'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: `_(@::).extend Backbone.Events` is an alternative to `_.extend @prototype, Backbone.Events` that might read better (depending on the local definition of *better* of course).

Comment: @muistooshort Yeap, and the polar opposite all-the-way-explicit alternative to `@::` is, in this case, `ViewHelpers.prototype` (for anyone wondering =D).

Comment: Very helpful post, a lot of insight into how Coffee and Backbone work for such a short answer!

Comment: Note that `ViewHelpers` is being extended (clobbered) by `Backbone.Events`, so don't expect to be able to define your own `on`, `off`, or `trigger` methods (e.g. to wrap the methods of `Backbone.Events` with the intention of invoking them via `super`)

Answer (score 1):

There's another way (from what @epidemian answered), which doesn't involve copying `Backbone.Events` into a new object to use as your prototype - instead, use `Object.create` to create a new object to use as your prototype, using `Backbone.Events` as *its* prototype.

```
class ViewHelpers
  @prototype = Object.create(Backbone.Events)
```

Now `ViewHelpers`' prototype is a new, empty object whose prototype is `Backbone.Events`. You can define methods on `ViewHelpers`' prototype without affecting `Backbone.Events`, but all the `Backbone.Events` methods are still available to `ViewHelpers`, without having to copy them into a new object. This not only saves (a miniscule amount of) memory, but if you ended up adding on to `Backbone.Events` later, all `ViewHelpers`s would see the change.

For this, you'll need either [a browser that has ES5's `Object.create` function](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/), or [an `Object.create` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

To build on the excellent answer by @epidemian I would add this, it's a bit of a hack but it allows you to write your class with the `extends` statement as you specified in the question (which lets you call `super` on all the `Backbone.Events` methods):

```
class Events
_.extend Events.prototype, Backbone.Events

class CustomEvents extends Events

    trigger: (event, etc...) ->
        # You can add overrides before
        super "custom:#{event}", etc...
        # or after the super class methods
```

It would be neat to work the `_.extend` call into the `Events.constructor` function but I couldn't make it work...